# Passing label of input text to bean

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, label, managed-bean

I have to pass input text label and value both to my bean. Can anyone give some hint how to go ahead. I am able to do so in select one input by using selectItems. but i am stuck now in input text.

Basically this is how my xhtml looks like the drop down model and inputmodel is dynamic list . So how do I get both label and values in description array.

```
<ui:repeat varStatus="loop" var="uimodel"
        value="#  {createTicketBaseBean.selectMenus.uiDropDownModels}">
    <h:panelGroup id="ui_drop_down" styleClass="atf-form-line" layout="block"
            rendered="#{createTicketBaseBean.displayDropdown}">
        <atf:selectOneInput componentId="severity_list" labelText="#{uimodel.label}"
                required="#{uimodel.mandatory}" tooltipText="#{I18N['key_tooltip_severity']}"
                value="#{createTicketBaseBean.descriptionList[loop.index]}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{uimodel.descriptionList}" />
        </atf:selectOneInput>
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>

<ui:repeat var="uimodel_input" value="#{createTicketBaseBean.selectMenus.uiInputTextModels}">
    <h:panelGroup id="ui_input_text" styleClass="atf-form-line" layout="block"
            rendered="#{createTicketBaseBean.displaySelectMenu}"
            style="#{createTicketBaseBean.selectMenus.showSeverityMenu ? '' : 'display:none'}">
        <atf:input componentId="input_category_labels" labelText="#{uimodel_input.label}"
                required="">
        </atf:input>
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: [What exactly do you need the label for in managed bean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I am setting it in a field called description which will have multiple label value pairs .

Comment: I am setting it in a field called description which will have multiple label value pairs .Basically description field will have multiple label value fields based on dynamic form based on web service response. This is yet another challenge setting all label - value pairs in one description field.I know its bit silly requirement but I need to do it.

Comment: So, it's part of the model? Why don't you store it in the model instead of hardcoding in the view?

Comment: I have edited my question. I am not clear how do i store it in model

Comment: You seem to already have it in the model. Well, problem solved. You only perhaps need to restructure the model so that all data is coupled to each other instead of being completely decoupled, which indeed makes it much harder to relate labels and inputs to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Ok as BelusC said I restructured the Model by adding an empty field and then storing my input text value in that filed. I then iterated it creating label -value pairs as labels too were coming from model.